# How to restore database into dockerized MS SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am using macbook and I need to browse locally MSSQL Server Database. However I am using docker and do not install dev tools, so I have found that there is dockerized MSSQL Server. I have used command:

```
docker run --name mssql-db \
    -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' \
    -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Lazar123!' \
    -p 1433:1433  \
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

to run docker container. And it was successful. Now I need to restore database from `PROFIT.bak`.

So I have copied `PROFIT.bak` into container:

```
docker cp `PROFIT.bak` <container>:/var/opt/mssql/data/
```

I can verify that this works because when I shell into container and navigate to that folder I can see .bak file there.

Now while I am into container I run command

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'Profit123!' -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [PROFIT] FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/data/PROFIT.bak'""
```

However running this command shows following error which I do not understand:

```
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server 083d438cc40d, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PROFIT.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server 083d438cc40d, Line 1
File 'ProfitCard' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PROFIT.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server 083d438cc40d, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PROFIT_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server 083d438cc40d, Line 1
File 'ProfitCard_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PROFIT_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Server 083d438cc40d, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 083d438cc40d, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Any help on how to restore this database?

Comment: If you read the errors, it *is* telling you the problem **and** the solution. Have a read of the error starting *"`File 'ProfitCard' cannot be restored`"*; it tells you *exactly* what to do.

Comment: @Larnu Sry but I still do not know what to do... can you please write full command for me...? Thanks

Comment: What about the error don't you understand or when you read the documentation about the command it's telling you to do, what about that didn't you understand, so we can explain it to you.

Comment: I fixed it, i did not know anything about restoring database from cli for SQL Server. I only used SSMS in the past. So I ended up adding WITH MOVE ProfitCard.mdf and ProfitCard_log.ldf to appopriate locations

Comment: Yes this is an an error in your import command that has nothing to do with Docker.  Its' hard for anyone to help you with this without knowing how your database is set up.

Comment: Yep, that's what you need to do; exactly as the error told you: *"`Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.`"*